# Why does a closed area represent a group of things in an Euler Diagram?

Tags: logic

Why does a closed area represent a group of things in an Euler Diagram?
This thinking is quite meta, but if I explain it using my words, I would say a closed area works as if the things in the world that fit the category are selected (highlighted like on a webpage), and when they are highlighted their boxes are checked or have a certain color on them. So the overlaping area means those items are selected multiple times (or have multiple colors on them).

**For example,**

[image]

All of the four-leg creatures in the world have red color on them.
All of the warm-blooded creatures in the world have yellow color on them.
All of the creatures in the world fit both categories have both red and yellow.
All elephants on earth have red and yellow, too. But since they are specified in the diagram, I would give it one more color, maybe green.
So, all elephants have three colors: red, yellow, and green.

I wonder whether they are people who interpret Euler Diagram this way?

Comment: A playful idea —associating the parameters of a Euler diagram with the colour parameters in [colour space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). One may improve on it (adjust the intensity according to the number of elements in each section, etc.). But more relevant to the art of data visualisation than to philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

### Caveat

Well, this question isn't a good fit for the site, but I can answer from the philosophy of language and linguistics.

### Answer

> Why does a closed area represent a group of things in an Euler Diagram?

In [cognitive semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_semantics), there is an idea called the [conceptual metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_metaphor). Essentially, the thesis is that the neurons responsible for creating the conceptualization of space and time can be repurposed for other abstractions. In this case, both Venn diagrams and Euler diagrams are essentially [graphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) that represent space; this is known By Lakoff and Nunez in their [*Where Mathematics Come From*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Mathematics_Comes_From) as the Metaphor of Containment.

For instance, if you say, what do you have IN mind, you subconsciously creating a metaphor between space and concepts, that is to say, the mind is a container in which things known as 'concepts' can be placed. From this, you might subscribe to [tabula rasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_rasa) which is a legitimate philosophical doctrine. Is the mind a physical container? Of course not, but we conduct our normal conversation as such because using the extensions to the metaphors is handy. Books "contain" ideas. Minds "contain" concepts. And we can think of moving the ideas into the minds.

What happens when you have elephants in one "bucket" and dogs in another? Then you merely visualize an overlap in regards to their properties. Both are four-legged. One can use areas, colors, or other properties to create analogies regarding propositional content and concepts, and those visual aids help people to understand in ways that lists or tabular presentation might not. A picture is worth a thousand words, right? Now, as far as coloring subspaces of regions in Venn and Euler diagrams, one can extend that tool however one likes. However, generally, the diagrams are meant to simplify understanding, so using additional graphemes or additional properties is generally limited to how useful it is in visualization. Here's a pic from WP's "Venn Diagram":

[image: Colors Used to Visualize 3D]

These days, the use of visual models is the chief subject of [data visualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_visualization) which is an important part of [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) in software development.